# Getting No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/circuit using C3P0PooledConnectionPool

Tags: servlets, c3p0

Hi I am using C3P0 connection pool and i get this error which is intermittent:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/circuit
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:66)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:76)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:66)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.assimilateResource(BasicResourcePool.java:787)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.acquireUntil(BasicResourcePool.java:548)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$000(BasicResourcePool.java:35)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:972)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:148)
```

Any Clue?

Comment: "*No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/circuit*". The JDBC driver which is supposed to be present on the class-path but actually it is not.

Comment: I have com.mysql.jdbc_5.1.5.jar in my lib folder.So what else need to be done?

Comment: If you showed the code which you might think the culprit of this exception then, someone might shed some light on it.

Comment: Should I show the code where i am making a DB Call or the configurations for the connection?